# How to implement deep linking in android with direct app open

Tags: java, android, kotlin, deep-linking, android-deep-link

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:host="account" android:scheme="sortifyd" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I have deep linking functionality where link will be shared to user if user click on it they will redirect to specific screen in out app.

while I have customized deep linking url like this **sortifyd://sortifyd.com/account?code=FESTIVE50**

but issue is when i'm sharing it in the whatsapp or anywhere it not clickable

[image]

I know if we want to open app directly then we must need to use like this
**sortifyd://sortifyd.com/account?code=FESTIVE50**

but how user will click on it.
you can check above whatsapp shared message and it's not in the form of link.
If i'm shared via Slack then it's creates as link and it's also clickable for end users
[image]

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="sortifyd.com"
                android:scheme="https"
                android:path="/account" />
        </intent-filter>
```

This is working fine **https://sortifyd.com/account?code=festive50**
and My app also shows in the promt

[image]

While the first one is my app but browsers also in the option as it's https link.

**So I want to share a link to users, and whenever user is going to tap on link it should directly open the app. is there any way?**

should i have to ask a backend developer to create https link and internally when user open that link created by backend developer they should hit **sortifyd://sortifyd.com/account?code=FESTIVE50** this internally so app can be directly open?

Best,
Nikul